# how to add conditional `dySeries()` calls in a pipe based on shiny inputs

Tags: r, shiny, dygraphs

I am building on a [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52325173/841405) provided by @Jon_Spring. I want to change some parameters of the dygraph based on the selected disaggregation. Everything flows through a pipe, so I started to look for [advice on conditional evaluation using pipes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30604107/r-conditional-evaluation-when-using-the-pipe-operator/30604360).

My thought was to use the `{if }` approach within the pipe:

```
{if(input$diss=="Total") 
      dySeries("1", label = "All") else 
      dySeries("man", label = "Male") %>% 
      dySeries("woman", label = "Female")
    }
```

This step comes after `dygraph()` is called. My idea was to say "if there is no disaggregation, use `dySeries("1", label = "All")`, otherwise use `dySeries("man", label = "Male") %>% dySeries("woman", label = "Female")`.

But I get an error:

> $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors

Am I on the right track, or is there a better way to create conditional plot parameters for dygraph based on inputs?

````
---
title: "test"
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    theme: bootstrap
runtime: shiny
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(flexdashboard)
library(tidyverse)
library(tibbletime)
library(dygraphs)
library(magrittr)
library(xts)
```

```{r global, include=FALSE}
# generate data
set.seed(1)
dat <- data.frame(date = seq(as.Date("2018-01-01"), 
                             as.Date("2018-06-30"), 
                             "days"),
                  sex = sample(c("male", "female"), 181, replace=TRUE),
                  lang = sample(c("english", "spanish"), 181, replace=TRUE),
                  age = sample(20:35, 181, replace=TRUE))
dat <- dplyr::sample_n(dat, 80)
```

Sidebar {.sidebar}
=====================================

```{r}

radioButtons("diss", label = "Disaggregation",
             choices = list("All" = "Total",
                            "By Sex" = "sex",
                            "By Language" = "lang"), 
             selected = "Total")
```

Page 1
=====================================

```{r plot}

renderDygraph({
  grp_col <- rlang::sym(input$diss)

  dat %>%
    mutate(Total = 1) %>% 
    mutate(my_group = !!grp_col) %>%
    group_by(date = lubridate::floor_date(date, "1 week"), my_group) %>%

    count() %>% spread(my_group, n) %>% ungroup() %>%
    padr::pad() %>% replace(is.na(.), 0) %>%

    xts::xts(order.by = .$date) %>%
    dygraph() %>%
    dyRangeSelector() %>%
    {if(input$diss=="Total") 
      dySeries("1", label = "All") else 
      dySeries("male", label = "Male") %>% 
      dySeries("female", label = "Female")
    } %>%
    dyOptions(
      useDataTimezone = FALSE, 
      stepPlot = TRUE,
      drawGrid = FALSE, 
      fillGraph = TRUE,
      colors = ifelse(input$diss=="Total", 
                      "blue",
                      c("purple", "orange"))
    )
})
```
````

Answer (score 1):

Eric!

I had a similar problem and this aproach solved it for me:

Inside the {if} you have to specify axactly where the element that comes through the pipe is going to fit in the dySeries, you do that by placing a dot (.) in the dySeries function.

Instead of the if you used, you could try the following:

```
{if(input$diss=="Total") 
  dySeries(., "1", label = "All") else 
  dySeries(., "man", label = "Male") 
}%>% 
{if(input$diss=="Total")
  .
else
  dySeries(., "woman", label = "Female")
}
```

I divided the {if} into two conditional evaluations, I don't know if it's going to work, but it's worth the try. You shouldn't get the error mentioned in the question when you use the dot. I had a [question about conditional evaluation by using pipes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58713038/how-do-i-send-multiple-dyseries-to-a-secondary-axis-based-on-checkbox-input-in-s/59288051#59288051)  and was able to solve it in a similar way, if you want to take a look.