# How do I send multiple dySeries to a secondary axis based on checkbox input in shiny?

Tags: r, shiny, r-dygraphs

I'm trying to plot a dyGraph using the lungDeaths timeseries, but I want "mdeaths" and "fdeaths" to be on the secondary axis, if at least one of them is selected alongside "ldeaths".

Here's a working example:

**global.R**

```
library(dygraphs)
library(shiny)
library(datasets)
library(stringr)

lungDeaths <- cbind(mdeaths, fdeaths)
```

**ui.R**

```
shinyUI(fluidPage(

titlePanel("Predicted Deaths from Lung Disease (UK)"),

sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(

        id="sidebar", width = 3,
        div(
            checkboxGroupInput(
                inputId = "selection", label = "Variables:",
                choiceNames = list("ldeaths",
                                   strong("mdeaths"),
                                   strong("fdeaths")
                                   ),
                choiceValues = c("ldeaths",
                                 "mdeaths",
                                 "fdeaths"), selected = "ldeaths"),
            uiOutput("rendered"),
            style = "font-size:75%"
        )

    ),
    mainPanel(
        dygraphOutput("dygraph")
    )
)
))
```

**server.R**

```
shinyServer(function(input, output) {

lungDeaths <- cbind(mdeaths, fdeaths, ldeaths)

rData <- reactive({
    rData <- ts(lungDeaths[,input$selection])
})

output$dygraph <- renderDygraph({

    if(length(input$selection) > 1 & length(str_subset(input$selection, 'ldeaths$'))>0){

        if(length(str_subset(input$selection, 'fdeaths$'))>0 & length(str_subset(input$selection, 'mdeaths$'))>0){
            dygraph(rData(), main = "Deaths from Lung Disease (UK)") %>% 
                dySeries("mdeaths", axis = 'y2') %>% 
                dySeries("fdeaths", axis = 'y2')
        }

        else if(length(str_subset(input$selection, 'mdeaths$'))>0){
            dygraph(rData(), main = "Deaths from Lung Disease (UK)") %>% 
            dySeries("mdeaths", axis = 'y2') 
        }
        else if(length(str_subset(input$selection, 'fdeaths$'))>0){
            dygraph(rData(), main = "Deaths from Lung Disease (UK)") %>% 
            dySeries("fdeaths", axis = 'y2')

        }
    }
    else
        dygraph(rData(), main = "Deaths from Lung Disease (UK)")
})
})
```

This code does what I want it to do, but I wanted to avoid using so many if's and else's, because the project I'm actually working with has 6 items that should go to y2 when selected. Is there any way to do it without having to specify each possibility?

I've already researched on [how to add dySeries based on input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52334944/how-to-add-conditional-dyseries-calls-in-a-pipe-based-on-shiny-inputs) and how to do [conditional evaluation when using pipes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30604107/r-conditional-evaluation-when-using-the-pipe-operator/30604360), but the answers I found so far don't work for me. I usually get an error that says:

> $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made it, so I'm posting the answer to help anyone who's been struggling with the same issue...

I was not using the if else correctly when trying to do the conditional pipe evaluation, that's why I kept receiving the error mentioned in the question.

It turns out that I had to use the dot (.) to specify exactly where the object before the pipe was supposed to be inserted in the following function, probably because the function was inside a conditional evaluation. The code bellow does exactly what I wanted it to do:

```
 output$dygraph <- renderDygraph({

        dygraph(rData(), main = "Deaths from Lung Disease (UK)") %>% 
            {
                if(length(str_subset(input$selection, 'mdeaths$')) > 0 )
                    dySeries(.,"mdeaths", axis = 'y2')
                else
                    .
            } %>% 
            {
                if(length(str_subset(input$selection, 'fdeaths$')) > 0 )
                    dySeries(.,"fdeaths", axis = 'y2')
                else
                    .
            }

})
```

The dygraph now shows the dyseries on the secondary axis, whenever they are selected as inputs

Answer (score 1):

You should do something like:

```
dg = dygraphs(rData, main="...") %>%
  dyAxis("y", label="...") %>%
  dyAxis("y2", label="...")

for(col in leftCols)
  dg = dg %>% dySeries(col, axis="y")
for(col in rightCols)
  dg = dg %>% dySeries(col, axis="y2")
```